# On a non-interference engine, do you have to replace the timing belt?

Tags: timing-belt, scheduled-maintenance

Lets say that I happen to know for a fact that my car has a non-interference type engine, and also has a timing belt.  Also, I'm broke.

Is there any reason to replace the timing belt as a maintenance item?  Will anything be harmed (other than loosing the use of my vehicle for a while) if I just let it ride and worry about it after it snaps?

Comment: This is what we call reactive.  You clearly shouldn't start an IT managed services company.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On non-interference motors there is no *compelling* reason to change out the belt on a schedule other than to ensure your vehicle does not leave you stranded at the most inopportune time. It will not damage anything if it does let go, but assume it will *always* leave you stranded.

Something to think about here is to ensure you know *exactly* which type of motor you have. While they exist, you must know almost all engines produced in the recent past are interference motors. ***Do not assume*** your motor is not. ***Know*** whether or not it is a non-interference type. Assuming it isn't will ensure engine destruction on a replacement level. Pay a small amount now versus a large amount later.

Comment: I didn't realize that non-interference were so uncommon.  Is it the case, worldwide, that most engines are interference?  (Just making sure we're not talking about "only smaller euro engines" or something.)

Comment: I'll put it this way (because I don't have hard statistics): If you don't know for sure your timing belt driven engine is interference or not, *assume it is*. You will never go wrong with that assumption.

Comment: Check this list out of interference engines.    http://yourcarangel.com/2014/07/interference-engines-complete-list/  In todays day and age I think it should be a crime to distribute an interference engine.

Comment: @DucatiKiller - Two things: 1) Date of list is 07/2014? 2) Doesn't include (at least) Jaguar V8's ... how "complete" is it? (What else has it left off?)